# LayoutInflater not working for Android

Tags: android, layout, view, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I am trying to add a LinearLayout as a child to another LinearLayout component, but it will not show up on the screen at all.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ReceivedMessage"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:showIn="@layout/content_chat">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/ProfilePicture"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:text="   Message"
    android:layout_width="305dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MessageText"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
Button testMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TestMessageButton);
    testMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            LinearLayout msgLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MessageLayout);

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.message_received, msgLayout, false);


            msgLayout.addView(v);
        }
    });
```

What is causing the component to not appear on the screen?

Comment: You just want to add a linearlayout to another linearlayout ? So whats that inflator ? Why yo used that ?

Comment: Because the parent LinearLayout is a vertical one, and is just used to sort. The horizontal LinearLayout, which is the one I want to insert, contains an image and text. I used inflator because you cannot clone a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not correct but I will answer it in two different ways

First, if the LinearLayout you want to add is in a different xml file then you can inflate the xml file and add it to parent LinearLayout in your Activity class like this

```
Button testMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TestMessageButton);
testMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        LinearLayout msgLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MessageLayout);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.message_received, null);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);

        msgLayout.addView(v);
    }
});
```

**I have updated my solution**. Part of the problem is in your layout file

This is the Activity class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout mainLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    Button addChatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_chat);
    addChatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout mView = (LinearLayout)vi.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, mainLayout, false);
            mView.setLayoutParams(params);
            mainLayout.addView(mView);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The xml layout file for Activity class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.inducesmile.mylinear.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_chat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="@string/add_chat"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, the layout file that contains the Linearlayout to be inflated and add to the root LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ReceivedMessage"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
android:visibility="visible">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/ProfilePicture"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/MessageText"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:paddingTop="14dp"
    android:paddingBottom="14dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My case is the first case, and I tried using the code, but the component still does not show up in the LinearLayout.

Comment: Add mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); and do you have any error in your logcat?

Comment: I've added the function and still no luck. Logcat isn't showing any errors either.

Comment: I just tweaked it a little and there is a result; the button moves position to the line above.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code now works. May I ask, what was the issue with the xml file, as to avoid making the same mistake again?

Answer (score 0):

based on [Inducesmile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40052354/3974487) if adding childs to the parent containers works then the problem may occur because the parent container is not placed inside a scrollview so all childs you are adding will not be visible to you if you want to make sure that the view already added just call parentlayout.getChildCount() after adding any child